# Issue getting DNS wild card A Record (*) working

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record, wins

I have a sub domain named subdomain under main domain named maindomain. Inside subdomain i have wild card (*) A Record that maps to a particular IP Address. This works fine and when i say ping `test1.subdomain.maindomain.com`, i get the reply back even if test1 does not exist.

This works as long as i don't have `Use WINS forward lookup` checked. When i check that option and provide WINS Server IP Addresses, it stops working.

Is there a way to implement wild card (*) A Record and have `Use WINS forward lookup` checked?

*Edit*

According to the question [DNS wildcard entry doesn't resolve correctly (Microsoft DNS Server)](https://serverfault.com/q/614854/113652), OP fixed his problem by unchecking `Use WINS forward lookup`. I am looking for a way to keep `Use WINS forward lookup` option checked and also have a (*) A Record

Comment: WINS? Do you have pre-Windows 2000 machines to support? If not, get rid of that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : it really is not in my hands to make that decision. I would have if i could have.

Comment: Well, maybe now you can press the issue a little harder.